# How do i achieve the following in HTML?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I wish to have a page that has a fixed height (without scroll bars). Then underneath the header a fluid height div that does have a scroll bar(not the entire page). Also, the width is to be fluid on the entire page.

This is illustrated below:
[Image of layout involving fixed-height header followed by scrolling area http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/9242/tmphh.png](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/9242/tmphh.png)

What should i do in HTML so that it works in all browsers including IE6 ?

**EDIT: CODE CHANGED, works in IE6,Firefix,Chrome, However, IE6 shows 4 scrollbars !!!**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
    HTML,BODY
    {
        height:100%;
    }
    .fullContainer
    {
        width:80%;
        height:40%;
        overflow:auto;
        position:relative;
    }

    /*-- Can only modify these --*/
    .header
    {
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0; 
        width: 100%; 

        height:40px;
        background-color:#eeeeee;
    }
    .content
    {
        position: absolute; 
        top: 40px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;

        overflow:auto;
    }
    .contentContainer
    {
        height:100%;
    }
    * html .fullContainer{ /*IE6 hack*/
        padding: 40px 0 0 0;
    }
    * html .content{ /*IE6 hack*/
        height: 100%; 
        width: 100%; 
    }
    /*-- Can only modify these --*/
</style>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<div>before content...</div>
<div class="fullContainer">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <!-- <div class="contentContainer"> -->
        <div class="content">
            This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.
            This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.
            This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.
            This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.
            This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.
            This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.
            This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.
            This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.
            This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.
            This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.
            This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.
            This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.
            This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.This is scroller content.
            <div style="width:1000px;background-color:#ccffcc;">long text</div>
        </div>
    <!-- </div> -->
</div>
<div>after content...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a question for http://Doctype.com/

Comment: @Salvin just in case your curious, your question is being discussed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41972/questions-illustrated

Comment: hi earlz, it may seem that i didnt take some effort before asking the question, however, check the code below to see what i have attempted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want internal scrolling on the bottom div, I'm assuming you want the bottom div to be fluid vertically (rather--fluid to browser window size, not to content) as well as horizontally. (Being fluid horizontally really doesn't have much to do with a any solution to a vertical offset.) And since that's the case, your header has to be a set height. If the bottom div doesn't need to be fluid vertically, you can just set `height` to the desired number and declare `overflow-y:scroll`.

For vertical fluidity, you'll need to use [conflicting absolute positions](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/), setting the bottom div to start just below where the top div ends and going down to the bottom of the page. Essentially:

```
#bottomDiv {
  position: absolute;    
  top: 100px; /* however tall your top div is */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Note the expression you'll have to use for IE6 (laid out in the article linked to, above).

**Update** Why can't you modify `.fullContainer`? If it's just that that's in another stylesheet, try anyway. The way CSS works, you can override anything that's come before it. So, if in your editable area you can add a fullContainer rule (which you should be able to, if you're editing the CSS file at all), you very likely could redefine that div to get rid of the width and height declarations (`width:auto` and `height:auto` should do) and similarly reset or override other things (e.g., `overflow:hidden` if necessary).

The other option is to try to make both your desired (new) top and bottom divs use `position:fixed`, but note that fixed positions are notoriously buggy on some browsers, and you might want to avoid it as fragile for laying out your whole site.

**Update 2** For IE6, you're using 100% height plus padding, which means it will be automatically too tall. In the [article I point to](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/), search for 'Creating the exception for IE5 and IE6' and use those expressions--if you can't put them in separate stylesheets, just use the star hack you're already using.

Comment: what about Fluid wrt a container and not to entire browser window ?

 check my code below ....

Comment: dude! i too assumed 2 of the 4 edges would be ignored..that's crazy cool.

Comment: Yeah, it was a mindwarp when I first read about it. Yay for A List Apart.

Comment: :)  
@Update, .fullcontainer cannot be modified for other reasons, FOA there is no such thing in my real code, its generated on-the-fly tag attached to document object without any id/class and i do not have access to that code.

The overflow:auto and position:relative are embedded styles

Comment: @Salvin Ah, that's a pain. An all-too-familiar one. If you can shimmy in an extra div around everything, including the header, you should be able to use conflicting absolutes to duplicate the dimensions of .fullcontainer and set overflow:hidden, and then, since it will be absolutely positioned and you can give it whatever styles you want, you should be able to defeat the IE6 problem (which most likely has to do with the box model and not positioning per se).

Comment: @Salvin, yeah, I know. But without an ID or way to narrow down your selectors so you get the right div, it might just be your best shot. If you can get to .fullcontainer with something like #someID > div > div (which IE6 won't understand) you can always go #someID div div {some:rule} and then #someID div div div {some:opposite-rule} to simulate the same thing. At this point it sounds like a question of cruft in your CSS or cruft in your HTML.

Comment: (This is assuming you've implemented expressions and removed the height:100% + padding that will give you scrollbars, and searched and nixed any unneeded margins/padding from the offending divs [as IE6 has those handy box model bugs].)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to simulate this is to give the header component the following attribute:

```
div.header {position: fixed;}
```

And give the above div a fixed height, while not doing so for the bottom div.

Comment: Adding position:fixed will take it out of flow, and will not give the bottom div individual scrollbars.

Comment: How exactly does it take anything out of the flow? The header will float over the bottom content, and there's no need for additional scrollbars on the bottom div.

Comment: Any declaration of position:fixed takes it out of flow: it's absolutely positioned relative to the browser window. You'll need some fix that offsets the bottom div as much as the top is tall.

Comment: I also take the OP to mean they want internal scrollbars.

Comment: Agree that OP has mentioned internal scrollbars, but note that I do use the word "simulate". It's not clear whether that's a strict requirement.

Comment: Though you did say 'simulate'. If you edit your answer (maybe to make clearer what they'll end up with?), SO will let me take off the downvote.

Comment: ..how's that? Let the downvote ride, I don't care. Just wanted to recognize I based my vote on something you excused yourself from in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do it?

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="header">

    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    *{padding:0;margin:0}
    body{overflow:hidden}
    #header,#wrapper{width:100%}
    #header{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;height:100px;background-color:#F00}
    #wrapper{position:fixed;height:100%;margin-top:100px;overflow:scroll}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this should do the trick

```
<body style="margin:0;width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden;">
  <div id="HeaderDiv" style="width:100%; height:100px; overflow:hidden; float:left;">
  </div>
  <div id="FluidDiv" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll; float:left;">
  </div>     
</body>
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: Your margin in the body tag could just be written "margin: 0". Much simpler and easier to read.